# Discrete Polynomial Ham-Sandwich Theorem proof

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, algebraic-topology, lebesgue-measure

***Discrete Polynomial Ham-Sandwich Theorem:*** Consider an algebraic hypersurface of degree $k$ in $\Bbb R^n$; let $Q$ be a polynomial of degree $k$ in $n$ variables. Define $m := \binom {n + k} {n}$ - 1. Let $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ be disjoint finite sets in $\Bbb R^n$. Then there exists $Q$ s.t.
$$
\forall i \in [m], \quad \left| A_i \cap \{ Q<0 \} \right|, \left| A_i \cap \{ Q > 0 \} \right| \le \frac {\left| A_i \right|} 2
$$

---

***Proof:*** I read a proof sketch for the Discrete Ham-Sandwich Theorem (see at the bottom) in which the "cutting"/bisecting surface is (degenerate to) only being a hyperplane (rather than an algebraic hypersurface). In this proof I got familiar with the "trick of balls with volume" (do you have a better name for that?). **My question is** why not using the same "trick of balls with volume" to reduce the discrete case into the continuous case (in which $A_1, \ldots, A_m \subset \Bbb R^n$ are disjoint bounded open sets), to which I already have a proof sketch (see below)?

Thank you.

---

***Proof sketch for Continuous Polynomial Ham-Sandwich Theorem:***
Let $Q$ be a polynomial of degree $k$ in $n$ variables. We want to show that $\exists Q$ s.t.
$$
\forall i \in [m], \quad vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q<0 \}\right) = vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q > 0 \}\right) = \frac {vol(A_i)} 2
$$
Note that $m$ is the number of non-constant monomials in $n$ variables of degree $\le k$. Thus we can make polynomials of degree $≤ k$ from points of the $m$-sphere $\Bbb{S^m}$ by identifying the vector $b = (b_0 , \ldots , b_m) ∈ \Bbb S^m$ with the polynomial $Q_b$ whose coefficients are precisely the values $b_0 , \ldots , b_m$. Define $f : \Bbb S^m \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ as follows

$$
f_i (b_0 , \ldots , b_m) = vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q_b<0 \}\right) - vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q_b > 0 \}\right)
$$
In other words, the $i$-th coordinate of $f$ measures how good the hyperplane $\{Q_b = 0\}$ is at bisecting the set $A_i$; In particular, this hyperplane bisects $A_i$ if and only if $f_i(b_0 , \ldots, b_m ) = 0$. $f$ can be shown to be continuous using the dominated convergence theorem. Intuitively, if we vary $b_0 , \ldots , b_m$ by just a little bit, then the polynomial $Q_b$ will only change a little bit, which means that the location of its zero-set $\{Q_b = 0\}$ will only change a little bit, so the value of each $f_i$ will only change a little bit; then since every $f_i$ is continuous, we get that $f$ is continuous. Also, $f$ is odd since every coordinate satisfy
$$
\begin{split}
f_i(-b_0 , \ldots, -b_m ) &= vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q_{-b}<0 \}\right) - vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q_{-b} > 0 \}\right) \\
&= vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q_{b} > 0 \}\right) - vol \left( A_i \cap \{ Q_{b} < 0 \}\right) \\
&= -f_i(b_0 , \ldots, b_m )
\end{split}
$$
By the Borsuk–Ulam theorem, $\exists (a_0 , \ldots , a_m) ∈ \Bbb S^m$ s.t. $f (a_0 , \ldots , a_m) = 0$. This implies that the hypersurface $\{Q_a = 0\}$ bisects each $A_i$.

---

***Proof sketch for Discrete Ham-Sandwich Theorem:*** For each $i \in [m]$ we define $A_i'$ to be the set of balls of radius $\epsilon$, centered around every point in $A_i$, namely $A_i' := \bigcup_{x \in A_i} B(x, \epsilon)$. We choose $\epsilon$ s.t. the hyperplane intersects in total at most $n$ balls. Therefore whenever $n$ is odd, we know that on one hand the hyperplane must intersect at least one ball for each $A_i'$, but on the other hand it can't intersect more than $n$ balls; concluding that the hyperplane intersect exactly one ball for each $A_i'$, and by symmetry the hyperplane must pass through the ball's center in order to bisect its volume. It means that the hyperplane bisects the original $A_i$ as required. Otherwise (i.e $n$ is even), it's possible to remove any point, do what we did for odd $n$, then return the point, since we are guaranteed that on each side of the hyperplane there won't be more than half of the points (after adding back the removed point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently it's possible to use the same "trick of balls with volume" (a proof sketch is available on Larry Guth's notes, [http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/PolyMethod/lect18.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Elguth/PolyMethod/lect18.pdf))